# Cannot find Django admin static file (404 not found)

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos

My Django project deployed on EC2 instance. Everything is fine except static files. Here is my project directory path tree

```
my_project
    └─admin
        ├── admin
        │   ├── admin
        │   ├── keywords
        │   ├── manage.py
        │   └── static
        ├── README.md
```

And this is my `settings.py` setting code about staticfiles

```py
# settings.py

debug=False

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'my_project/static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_ROOT
]
```

And this is my `nginx.conf` files

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static {
    alias /static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/devel/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

And also my machine's environments:

> Centos 7.9
> python 3.6.8
> Django 4.0.6

I already did `python manage.py collectstatic` command.

When I enter into this project's Admin page, Every UI have loaded without CSS and JS though.

Is somewhere of my setting is wrong? I wonder why django cannot find any static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your BASE_DIR is the same as /usr/share/nginx/html, and the BASE_DIR/myproject/static exists and has content, try

```
location /static/ {
    root /myproject/;
}
```

(Using root rather than alias as the end directories are the same, as per [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias))

I am assuming your earlier root definition will prefix the location - if not you might have to use `root /usr/share/nginx/html/myproject/` explicitly instead